# How do I upgrade a program on HP-UX?

Tags: hp-ux, swinstall

I've noticed HP-UX `swinstall` can install two different versions, or releases of the same program.

But if I want to upgrade a program?

Usually I do:

```
swremove NAMEOFPRODUCT
swinstall NAMEOFPRODUCT
```

Is there an upgrade option like Linux (`upgradepkg`, `rpm -Uvh`, etc..)
on HP-UX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is possible to upgrade using option "Match What Target Has"
using the gui,i don't know if is possible even with cli.

[Software Distributor Administration Guide: HP-UX 11i v1, 11i v2, and 11i v3 > Chapter 2 Installing Software](http://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/5992-4826/ch02s01.html)

"Match What Target Has examines your current Installed Product Database to match your existing filesets with new filesets (those with the same names) that you are going to install. This feature is most helpful when you are updating a system to newer versions of the same software. This option can be set from the Options Editor. If multiple targets are specified, the first target in the list is used as the basis for selections."

Comment: `swinstall` will upgrade a bundle/package. You will get multiple versions of software if the bundles/products don't match.

Comment: yes i explain how to avoid the multiple versions,there is no way other to remove and reinstall with newest version,for a good upgrade the only way is to write a script

Comment: It sounds like the packages you are installing haven't been setup correctly. You could try rebundle the packages instead. Uninstalling (esp core packages) could have unintended consequences.

Comment: Yes i know is dangerous,but for example,i have sendmail 14.9,i want to upgrade to 15.1 package,how to do without removing first old sendmail?

Comment: Where are you getting the packages from ? HPUX connect (porting and archive)

Comment: No,made by me,with swpackage